# How to turn one long string of hearts into a pot?

Tags: indoors, propagation

I have a [string of hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceropegia_woodii) plant growing in a small pot. It is currently just one very long (~1m) string, dangling down.

I'd like to start turning it into many different strings, filling a pot. What's the best way to do this? Can I just cut pieces off and hope they will re-root? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different methods of propagating a string of hearts.

If your plant has them, the tubers (looking like balls/beads) on the string can be planted and will grow into new plants. Put multiple in one pot and you get lots of strings right from the start.

C. woodii will also root from cuttings, 2-3 inch / 8-10 cm sections will work fine. Note that you are working with a succulent, so give the cuttings a few days to dry off before planting or you risk rot. As above, multiple cuttings can go in one pot.

But the probably easiest version is to simply lift the string(s) and place them across the pot (fixing is optional when gravity holds them in place, but you can use some u-shaped wires), where they will typically send out roots at the places that touch the soil. I remember one plant in my mum’s home that got that treatment simply to “stow away” excessively long strands and then grew into a veritable net.

Comment: Taking the cutting approach, I would have to cut up the one string into a lot of small pieces? Does the original string keep growing after that?

Comment: Good question. I never paid too much attention back then when we had the plant. If you want to play it safe, I’d recommend the last method. You can always cut the loop once the string has rooted and see what happens.